# Change the name of the dropdown menu by selected link name

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

First of all, I will paste my whole html code here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
     
    <!-- Postgresqlabfragen -->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <ul>
          <li> <strong>Verfügbare Abfragen:</strong> </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{url_for('server.epex')}}">
              EPEX
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{url_for('server.post')}}">
              Show Partner
            </a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">EPEX Strompreise</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group me-2">
          </div>
          
 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Aktueller Stand
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(1)">Aktueller Stand</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(1)">Letzte Woche</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(2)">Maximum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
        </div>
      </div>

      <img id="graph" src="" width="900" height="600" >
      
    <!-- <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='EPEX_dashboard.js') }}"></script>-->
    <script>
    function loadNewGraph(id){
    
    let req_url = '/postgresql/epex/get_graph/'
    //if (window.location.href.includes("partner")){
    //    req_url = '/postgresql/partner/get_graph/'
    //}
    
    
    // ajax call to url get_graph, cf.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", req_url + id, true);
    xhttp.send();
    
    xhttp.onload = function(e){
        imgurl = document.getElementById('graph')
        imgurl.src = '/static/Bilder/new_plot.png' + "?ts=" + Date.now()
        
    }

    
    }
    loadNewGraph(0)
    </script>
  </body>

{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that I want to change the button name "Aktueller Stand" with the selected one.
In this case I have 3 possible selections:

'

Aktueller Stand

Letzte Woche

Maximum'

But clicking on them still leaves in the window "Aktueller Stand". I didnt find a satysfying solution on the internet. Can you help me out guys?
Here is a photo of my linked Bootstrap Dropdownmenu:
https://ibb.co/gbKk53Z "dropdown menu"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your button to use it in js. I said `lnkButton`, you can name anything.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="lnkButton">
```

Add a text input to your function as the click options text :

```
function loadNewGraph(id, text){
...
```

Use this input to change the button text at the very bottom of your function

```
   ...
   document.getElementById("lnkButton").innerText = text;
}
```

Add text input values into your link as their button text :

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(0, 'Aktueller Stand')">Aktueller Stand</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(1, 'Letzte Woche')">Letzte Woche</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(2, 'Maximum')">Maximum</a></li>
```

Finally add the first button text as the initial value when you call your function:

```
loadNewGraph(0, 'Aktueller Stand');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the content of the clicked option as second parameter like this

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            Aktueller Stand
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <!-- The keyword this refer to the a tag -->
                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(this, 0)">Aktueller Stand</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(this, 1)">Letzte Woche</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(this, 2)">Maximum</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    
    <img id="graph" src="" width="900" height="600" />
    <script>
    // Your dropdown button you can give an id for more specificity
    let dropdownBtn = document.querySelector(".dropdown button");
        function loadNewGraph(el, id) {
            // Update label depending on what you click
            dropdownBtn.innerText = el.innerText;
            //.....
        }
        // Default option
        loadNewGraph(dropdownBtn, 0);
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Batu.Khan and the rest of community :-).

I post here my solution leaned on the answer of Batu.kha, which is now working wonderful.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
     
    <!-- Postgresqlabfragen -->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <ul>
          <li> <strong>Verfügbare Abfragen:</strong> </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{url_for('server.epex')}}">
              EPEX
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{url_for('server.post')}}">
              Show Partner
            </a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">EPEX Strompreise</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group me-2">
          </div>
          
 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="lnkButton">
      Aktueller Stand 
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(0,'Aktueller Stand')">Aktueller Stand</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(1, 'Letzte Woche')">Letzte Woche</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="loadNewGraph(2, 'Maximum')">Maximum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
        </div>
      </div>

      <img id="graph" src="" width="900" height="600" >
      
    <!-- <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='EPEX_dashboard.js') }}"></script>-->
    <script>
    function loadNewGraph(id,text){
    
    let req_url = '/postgresql/epex/get_graph/'
    //if (window.location.href.includes("partner")){
    //    req_url = '/postgresql/partner/get_graph/'
    //}
    
    
    // ajax call to url get_graph, cf.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", req_url + id, true);
    xhttp.send();
    
    xhttp.onload = function(e){
        imgurl = document.getElementById('graph')
        imgurl.src = '/static/Bilder/new_plot.png' + "?ts=" + Date.now()
        
    }

    document.getElementById("lnkButton").innerText = text;
}
    
    loadNewGraph(0, 'Aktueller Stand')
    
    </script>
  </body>

{% endblock %}
```